# toggle boolean in react needed, but not quite sure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know I need to incorporate a boolean into this, I am just not entirely sure how.

I want to click on the button event and toggle between the data "price" (data.js) put into order of cheapest price and STOP at 5 objects. But then click the same button and return the data to the previous dataspace default

Can anyone help?

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import FeedContainer from "./FeedContainer";
import { useState } from "react";
import FeedData from "./data/data";

function App() {
  const [dataspace, setDataspace] = useState(FeedData);

  const topFivePrice = () => {
    setDataspace([...dataspace].sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1)));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={topFivePrice}>TOP 5 prices</button>
        <FeedContainer dataspace={dataspace} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

data.js

```
const FeedData = [
  { name: 'Item A', price: 125, id:1 },
  { name: 'Item B', price: 230, id:2 },
  { name: 'Item C', price: 295, id:3 },
  { name: 'Item D', price: 245, id:4 },
  { name: 'Item E', price: 900, id:5 },
  { name: 'Item F', price: 875, id:6 },
  { name: 'Item G', price: 235, id:7 },
  { name: 'Item H', price: 400, id:8 },
]

export default FeedData
```

FeedCard.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './components/shared/Card'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function FeedCard({item}) {

  // const handleClick = (item) => {
  //   console.log(item)
  // }

  

  return (
    <Card >
        <div style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
          Name : {item.name}<br/>
          The Price is £{item.price}
        </div>
    </Card>
  )
}


export default FeedCard
```

FeedContainer.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import FeedCard from './FeedCard'
import Card from './components/shared/Card'


const FeedContainer = ({dataspace}) => {

    return (
        <div className='feedback-list'>
            {dataspace.map((item ) => (
                <FeedCard key ={item.id} item={item} />     
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}




export default FeedContainer
```

Comment: This could be a good case for `useMemo`. I guess I can't format in comments, and my rep isn't high enough to leave an answer right now so apologies for the mess, but it'd be something like

`const [shouldLimitTopFive, setShouldLimitTopFive] = useState(false);

const dataspace = useMemo(() => {
  if (!shouldLimitTopFive) {
    return FeedData;
  }
  return [...FeedData].sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1)).slice(0, 5);
}, [shouldLimitTopFive]);`

Comment: hello mate, doesnt seem to work  but maybe I am missing something, do i need to replace the onClick? (button onClick={topFivePrice}>TOP 5 prices</button>)

Comment: oh, at that point your button's `onClick` would toggle the boolean; `onClick={() => setShouldLimitTopFive(x => !x)}`

Comment: Thanks Ben worked a treat

Comment: hey Ben. can you explain what this is doing for me if thats ok? i get the majority but just want to make sure

Comment: There are some good answers that were submitted, but the idea is that state drives complexity, so we want as little state as possible in our apps. So instead of making dataspace it's own piece of state, we basically make it a computed property. You can sort of think of it as we're defining a way to see our data through another pair of glasses, and then creating a switch to flip between seeing the original data, or seeing it through our new lens.

Answer (score 2):

**Toggle views**

We primarily just need to toggle between a sorted view and the default view. That can be done with a simple boolean state variable to track the current view.

```js
const [isSortedView, setIsSortedView] = useState(false);

// ...

<button onClick={() => setIsSortedView((prev) => !prev)}>TOP 5 prices</button>
```

**Update data view depending on toggle**

Then we need to display the correct view to the user depending on the state of the toggle. This is a derived state value, so this is a textbook use-case of the [`useMemo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo) hook.

```js
const dataspace = useMemo(() => (
  isSortedView 
    ? FeedData 
    : [...FeedData].sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1)).slice(0,5)
), [isSortedView]);
```

**Avoid resorting every time the user clicks**

You also don't need to recalculate the top 5 prices every time the user clicks the button; only when the data changes (which in this app is only on initial load). We can do that with another `useMemo` hook.

```js
const top5Prices = useMemo(() => (
  [...FeedData].sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1)).slice(0,5)
), []);
```

**Putting it all together**

And then the final code updates look like:

```js
function App() {
  const [isSortedView, setIsSortedView] = useState(false);

  const top5Prices = useMemo(() => (
    [...FeedData].sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1)).slice(0,5)
  ), []);

  const dataspace = useMemo(() => (
    isSortedView ? FeedData : top5Prices
  ), [isSortedView]); 
  

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={() => setIsSortedView((prev) => !prev)}>TOP 5 prices</button>
        <FeedContainer dataspace={dataspace} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments this is a good example for using `useMemo`.

We create a variable `topFiveData` which only updates when `dataspace` changes. We add a extra state for the toggle functionality and based on the `showTopFivePrice` we decide what data to pass to the `FeedContainer`

```js
function App() {
  const [dataspace, setDataspace] = useState(FeedData);
  const [showTopFivePrice, setShowTopFivePrice] = useState(false);

  const topFiveData = useMemo(() => {
    return [...dataspace]
      .sort((a, b) => (a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1))
      .slice(0, 5);
  }, [dataspace]);

  const toggleTopFivePrice = () => {
    setShowTopFivePrice((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={toggleTopFivePrice}>TOP 5 prices</button>
        <FeedContainer dataspace={showTopFivePrice ? topFiveData : dataspace} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```